# How can I toggle texts and icons using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an [accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/bpaxpuhz/1/show/).

[image]

When I click on `show details` :

- the accordion content will expand,
- the text will change from `show details` to `hide details`
- the icon will change from `+` to `x`
- click on it again should toggle back to its original state.

[image]

I couldn't get it to work. When I click on it, it stuck on the `HIDE DETAILS` state forever.

---

JS

```
 $(".show-details-sk-p").click(function () {
     $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("HIDE DETAILS");
     $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/remove.png");
 });
```

---

Can someone please give me a little push here ?

[I've put together a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/bpaxpuhz/1/)  - just in case it is needed.

Comment: you never change the text back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspected the aciton and element behavior, find that `#sk-p-r` will have class `in` to decide whether its collapsed or not.

```
 $(".show-details-sk-p").click(function () {
     var isCollapse = $('#sk-p-r').hasClass('in');
     var text = isCollapse ?  'SHOW DETAILS' : 'HIDE DETAILS';
     var img = isCollapse ? 'http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/plus.png' : 'http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/remove.png'
     $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text(text);
     $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", img);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added a boolean variable which is toggled whenever the accordion is clicked. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westlife_8/3wepouy5/)

```
var show=false; //indicates whether the accordion is hidden
$(".show-details-sk-p").click(function () {
if(!show){
 $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("HIDE DETAILS");
 $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/remove.png");
    show=true;
}
else{
    $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("SHOW DETAILS");
     $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/plus.png");
    show=false;
}
});
```

I have used the show variable to determine what text to display on the accordion.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways you can do this but your problem is that your 'click' doesn't have any way to set the 'show details' state from the code you have there.

In a really simple solution for this:

```
 $(".show-details-sk-p").click(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('open')
     if($(this).hasClass('open') === true){
         $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("HIDE DETAILS");
         $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/remove.png");
     }else{
         $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("SHOW DETAILS");
         $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/plus.png");
     }
 });
```

This is one way to do it.  I'm adding a class to the element here to track state and then conditionally setting the image and text based on that state to give you a true toggle.   There are likely smarter and more efficient ways to do this but this should be a simple enough example to point you into the right direction.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly compare booleans like that. `if ($(this).hasClass('open')) { ... }` will work.

Comment: I was trying to make it overly explicit so it was simple to understand as possible but yes definitely not needed to compare

Comment: You shouldn't teach bad patterns like that, though. Instead, link to the API where it explains that [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revert text and image when collapsing an accordion

```js
/* JavaScript */
$(".show-details-sk-p").click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('shown') === true) {
    $(this).data('shown', false);
    $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("SHOW DETAILS");
    $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/plus.png");
  } else {
    $(this).data('shown', true);
    $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text("HIDE DETAILS");
    $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src", "http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/remove.png");
  }
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

.sk-p-dash {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.panel {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.sk-p {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
.panel-title,
.panel-body {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.show-details-txt-sk-p-r {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
.show-details-sk-p {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.show-details-sk-p .icon-sk-p-r-toggle {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row sk-p">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">

            PRE-REQUISITE(S) FOR ALL SKILLS IN EXERCISE

            <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#sk-p-r" class="show-details-sk-p pull-right">
              <span class="show-details-txt-sk-p-r">SHOW DETAILS</span>
              <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r-toggle" src="http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/plus.png">
            </span>

          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="sk-p-r" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">


            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <span>SOLVING EQUATIONS BY ADDITION OR SUBSTRACTION </span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="sk-p-dash">
                <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s6.postimg.org/m4phsikzh/review_video.png">
                <span>WATCH VIDEO</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s6.postimg.org/6yjg1kuyl/review_pdf.png">
                <span>REVIEW LESSON</span>
              </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <span>GRAPHING INEQUALITIES IN ONE VARIABLE </span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="sk-p-dash">
                <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s6.postimg.org/m4phsikzh/review_video.png">
                <span>WATCH VIDEO</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s6.postimg.org/6yjg1kuyl/review_pdf.png">
                <span>REVIEW LESSON</span>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply toggle

better store the string values in variables

```
var txtHide = "HIDE DETAILS";
var txtShow = "SHOW DETAILS";
var rmvImage = "http://s6.postimg.org/e9eydpbct/remove.png";
var plsImage = "http://s6.postimg.org/bglqtob0d/plus.png";

$(".show-details-sk-p").click(function () {
     $(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text($(".show-details-txt-sk-p-r").text()==txtHide ? txtShow :txtHide );
     $(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src",$(".icon-sk-p-r-toggle").attr("src")==rmvImage ? plsImage :rmvImage );
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/bpaxpuhz/2/